Image conversion from .tiff (500 ppi) to .jpg keeping the (same) resolution
We are trying to convert a fingerprint .tiff image with a 500 ppi resolution to .jpg keeping the same resolution.
We managed to convert it but it seems that the resolution information is lost during the conversion (our biometric program does not recognize the .jpg file resolution as 500 ppi)
Is there a way to make sure that the resolution information is encoded in the .jpg file ?
We tried to use the suggestions from the following link:
converting tiff to jpeg in python
But it didn't work.

Converting a TIFF to a JPEG then Exif file format would be the natural choice to preserve as much of the TIFF file's original metadata in the new image as possible. However, standard JPEG compression is lossy so it would not be my choice of format for reference biometric data. PNG might be better suited to the task.

Use ImageMagick's command called convert. Simply, convert -quality 100 your_file.tiff your_file.jpg.
